# How to delete SQLite3 database row using Tkinter Treeview selection

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter, treeview, delete-row

I am trying to delete the sqlite3 DB row by selecting the same Treeview row and deleting it. my goal is to delete the Treeview row as well as sqlite3 DB at the same time, using the selection then delete button.

I have tried the following:

```py
  #inserting values on DB 
def addexpensetotable(self):
       self.expensevalues = (self.expensdatevar.get(),self.expensevaluevar.get(), 
       self.expenseselectvar.get()) 
       self.expensetree.insert("", END, values=self.expensevalues)
 
       self.cursorObj.execute("""INSERT INTO carexpenses2(cartype, carmodel, carlincesplate, 
       year, orginalcarprice, expensedate, expensetype,expensevalue, 
       cartotalprice)VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)""",expensevaluesfordb)

 
# trying to delete DB row by selecting the row from Treeview and deleting it in both (sqlite3, Treeview table)
def deleterows_tree_db(self):
    self.con = sqlite3.connect('car dealership.db')
    self.cursorObj = self.con.cursor()
  
    self.selected_item = self.expensetree.selection()[0]
    for self.selected_item in self.expensetree.selection():
      self.cursorObj.execute("DELETE FROM carexpenses2 WHERE id=?",
                               (self.expensetree.set(self.selected_item, "expense type"),))
    self.con.commit()
    self.expensetree.delete(self.selected_item)
 
 #some of Treeview code, in case it would help and clarify more       
def expenses(self):
    self.expensetree = ttk.Treeview(self.expenseframe, show="headings", style='MyStyle.Treeview')
    self.expensetree['columns'] = ("اdate", "value type", "expense type")
    self.expensetree.pack()

    self.expensetree.heading("expense type", text="expense type")
    self.expensetree.heading("value type", text="value type")
    self.expensetree.heading("date", text="اdate")
```

results of the previous code:
the row is deleted from The Treeview table without deleting it from the sqlite3 database.
if there is any lack of explanation I will clarify more

Comment: What is the actual problem? Are you having trouble figuring out which items to delete, or are you having problems deleting them? Do you still have the problem if you remove all of the tkinter code and replace it with some hard-coded strings?

Comment: Should `id = ?` be `expensetype = ?` in the DELETE SQL statement?

Comment: @BryanOakley I am trying to create a function that will delete the database row by selecting the same row in the Treeview then delete it so the db row and treeview row is deleted at the same time.

Comment: @acw1668, thank you for your response I will try to change the id=? to expensetype=?,,

Comment: @acw1668 thanks a lot man you're incredible.